# Can't correctly stream x264 video to mobile via RTSP

Tags: android, rtsp, aac, mencoder, x264

I'm creating mobile version of YouTube-like website. And i'm going to use Darwin Streaming Server for streaming low-res clips compressed with x264 and NeroAAC and hinted with MP4Box.

When i'm playing it with VLC player streaming works fine, as expected. When i'm trying to open URL with my HTC Hero, it switches to player mode, then starts "loading video" animation, then after some time it shows "unable to connect to server". Sample movies provided with DSS streamed fine regardless bitrate.

I tried few encoding options, but always the same result. I suspect nocabac and level=11 but it didn't changed nothing.

Is there some more specific encoding options for such type?

Thank You!

Comment: Is this a programming question (i.e. are you developing an app) or is this as a user? If the latter, you should try going to Super User or Force Close instead. If it really is a programming question, could you make it more clear how your app is involved in this process? (You can edit your question to provide that info, which is better than leaving a comment below this.)

Comment: Yes it is developer question. i'll fix topic now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

264 and AAC are supported, but is better to use:

```
a)RTSP streaming URL for mobile video playback. H.263 video and AMR audio.
or
b)RTSP streaming URL for mobile video playback. MPEG-4 SP video and AAC audio.
```

Android Streaming is only supported with 3gp format files

```
 rtsp://myStreamingserver/myvideo.3gp
```